# Ellipsis or semantically incomplete sentence?

Tags: ellipses

I've got a resource, say a web-page. The page represents a product that belongs to one of the categories. For instance, Toys(category) -> Robocop (product). 
There's a link on the page that takes user to another page with suggestions on places where the toy can be bought. Is it going to be grammatically wrong to entitle this link "Where to buy" or it's fine to appeal to ellipsis in such situations ?
Thank you.

Comment: [Apple](http://www.apple.com/buy/): [Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/business/smb/en-xg/wheretobuy/ready.aspx?sender=3); [Frito Lay](http://www.fritolay.com/our-snacks/where-to-buy.html); [Canada Goose](http://www.canada-goose.com/where-to-buy/); and [tens of millions of others](https://www.google.de/search?q=%22where+to+buy%22).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wh-questions (except for why-questions) without a subject and with a to-infinitive as the verb are occasionally found as inquiries:

What to do next? (that means - What should I do next?) 
Who to see?
Which way to go?    etc.

So "Where to buy" is absolutely okay